# Acquiring the last 3 records from a database in ascending order using mySQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a simple php file to read the last 3 records added to my database in phpMyAdmin. The problem I face is that I want the last 3 added records in ascending order and I can only get them in descending order. I tried the following code which worked for some other people but does not work for me in phpMyAdmin.

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM studio ORDER BY studioId DESC LIMIT 3
)
ORDER BY studioId;
```

This is how I implemented the code into the php file.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM studio ORDER BY studioId DESC LIMIT 3) ORDER BY studioId";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo $row["studioName"]." ".$row["studioAddress"]." ".$row["studioPCode"]." ".$row["studioTelNo"]."<br/>";
    }
} else {
    echo "There Are No Studios Added";
}
```

For some reason the above code only works when I replace the first line of the above code with this line.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM studio ORDER BY studioId DESC LIMIT 3";
```

This is the code I used to create the table studio.

```
CREATE TABLE Studio (     
    studioId INT(5) NOT NULL,      
    studioName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,      
    studioAddress VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,      
    studioPCode VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,      
    CONSTRAINT
        ck_studioPCode CHECK(studioPCode LIKE '___ ___'),      
        studioTelNo VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,      
        CONSTRAINT ck_studioTelNo CHECK(LEN(studioTelNo) = 11),      
    PRIMARY KEY(studioId),      
    UNIQUE(studioName)      
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aliasing, this might work

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM studio ORDER BY studioId DESC LIMIT 3) AS stdId ORDER BY studioId";
```

Try this code and let me know if it's still not working

Comment: YES THIS WORKS, thanks a lot Rahul. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need below query:

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT * FROM studio ORDER BY studioId DESC LIMIT 3) z
ORDER BY z.studioId;
```

First get the latest 3 data in a subquery.

Create an alias of that query that will treat it as a table.

Sort the records in ascending order